# Android start up launching wrong activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-manifest

I have Changed the activity that I want to run first from MainActivity to another. I did this by editing Android manifest and moving this bit of code:

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

My manifest now looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="si.comtron.tronpos" >
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host" />

<!-- calendar -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />

<!-- camera -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

<!-- client -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
<!-- Authenticator -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
<!-- Shortcut -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
<!-- Wifi -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

<android:uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<android:uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
    tools:replace="android:icon,android:theme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="sensor"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".bluetooth.DeviceListActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/select_device"
        android:screenOrientation="sensor" />

<!-- android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize" -->
<activity
    android:name=".BasicDataActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="sensor" >
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".AnalysisActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
    android:screenOrientation="sensor" />
<activity
    android:name=".authorization.AuthenticatorActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
    android:label="@string/account_register"
    android:screenOrientation="sensor" />
<activity
    android:name=".authorization.LocalAuthenticatorActivity"
    android:label="@string/account_register"
    android:screenOrientation="sensor" />
<activity
    android:name=".authorization.SingUpActivity"
    android:label="@string/account_register"
    android:screenOrientation="sensor" />

<service android:name=".authorization.TronPosAuthenticatorService" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator" />
    </intent-filter>

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator"
        android:resource="@xml/authenticator" />
</service>
<activity
    android:name=".CountryPicker"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:noHistory="true" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".UnitActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_unit" >
</activity>
```

When I run it on my mobile phone and tablet (from android studio) I get the error below and the app doesent launch automatically like before. But when I click the icon it starts normally with the right activity first.

But when I use the emulator the right activity launches only on first install then the previously set activity does.

I have no idea why this is happening. I compleatly uninstaled app and reinstalled, I cleaned my project, rebuilt it, nothing seems to make a difference and I can't find a problem in my manifest. Any ideas?

And the error:

```
Launching application: com.package/com.package.MainActivity.
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: am start -D -n "com.package/com.package.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=si.comtron.tronpos/.MainActivity }
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=si.comtron.tronpos/.MainActivity } from null (pid=3636, uid=2000) not exported from uid 10104
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1465)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1419)
at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivityAsUser(ActivityManagerNative.java:2211)
at com.android.commands.am.Am.runStart(Am.java:680)
at com.android.commands.am.Am.onRun(Am.java:270)
at com.android.internal.os.BaseCommand.run(BaseCommand.java:47)
at com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:76)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:243)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Remove   `android:noHistory="true" ` in the manifest and try.

Comment: I need noHistory since this activity should not be accessed by back button after we get pass it.

Comment: @ranjith I tried without noHistory just to be sure and the results were the same.

Answer (score 0):

Have you clean your project after change launcher activity? if not then do it, may solve your problem.

Comment: Yes I cleaned and rebult my project but no difference. :(

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Eclipse`, maybe you need to `Project`-->`Clean` your project.
If you are using `Android Studio`, you may do this: `Build`--->`Rebuild Project` or `Clean Project`. Maybe caches cause things like this.

PS:see `java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent`, you need add some permissions.

Comment: yes I cleaned and rebult my project but no difference.

Comment: I have edited my answer, take a look again.

Comment: What kind of permision do i need for choosing the starting activity? Shouldn't this be a default thing..?

Answer (score 0):

can you change these

```
<android:uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<android:uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
```

to

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
     />
```

Comment: If this was the problem the first activity would still launch, but it would leave the stack after it finishes. But it doesent launch in the first place.

Comment: Tried but no difference :(

Comment: does it show the same error? if not update the code and logcat.

Comment: I have found the answer :) it's this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27047127/3959584