# App runs on emulator but not device?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, device

The app I am developing in android studio works perfectly on my emulator but for some reason when I try to install/run it on my device nothing shows up on the screen (I have a Samsung Galaxy Note Edge). I tried running it on a different project and it worked perfectly fine. If anyone has encountered this problem please help. I have the correct drivers and have restarted my device and android studio, Thanks for the help!

Here is the event log:

```
Waiting for device.
Target device: samsung-samsung_sm_n915a-190dd827
Uploading file
    local path: C:\Users\Dave\Desktop\Sample Code\Sample Code finalized\LiveWallPaperTake_3\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
    remote path: /data/local/tmp/wallpaper_live.com.dave.livewallpapertake_3
No apk changes detected. Skipping file upload, force stopping package instead.
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: am force-stop wallpaper_live.com.dave.livewallpapertake_3
Launching application: wallpaper_live.com.dave.livewallpapertake_3/wallpaper_live.com.dave.livewallpapertake_3.OpenGLES20Activity.
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: am start -n "wallpaper_live.com.dave.livewallpapertake_3/wallpaper_live.com.dave.livewallpapertake_3.OpenGLES20Activity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=wallpaper_live.com.dave.livewallpapertake_3/.OpenGLES20Activity }
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=wallpaper_live.com.dave.livewallpapertake_3/.OpenGLES20Activity } from null (pid=5184, uid=2000) not exported from uid 10038
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1540)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1493)
at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivityAsUser(ActivityManagerNative.java:2553)
at com.android.commands.am.Am.runStart(Am.java:768)
at com.android.commands.am.Am.onRun(Am.java:307)
at com.android.internal.os.BaseCommand.run(BaseCommand.java:47)
at com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:102)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:255)
```

Comment: Try the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19829507/android-java-lang-securityexception-permission-denial-starting-intent

Comment: Is `OpenGLES20Activity` your main/launcher activity?

Comment: This isn't a problem in the java code, but it might be one in the AndroidManifest.xml or it might be the IDE trying to use ADB to launch the wrong activity (something it may get away with on the emulator where adb runs as root)

Comment: @Android777 yes, OpenGLES20Activity is my main launcher activity

Comment: I got it to work, just needed to change some things around in the manifest.

Comment: @Dashboarrd, what things? I have the same issue...

Comment: I had the same issue, but only the full OS reinstalletion at my Android device helped me.