# Android starting WebBrowser Intent produces SecurityException

Tags: android, android-intent

I trying to send URL with file to web activity with:

```
public static void startDownloadFileActivity(com.app.model.File file, String link) {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(link);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    String mime = "*/*";
    MimeTypeMap mimeTypeMap = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
    if (mimeTypeMap.hasMimeType(file.getMimeType())) {
        mime = file.getMimeType();
    } else if (mimeTypeMap.hasExtension(MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(file.getTitle()))) {
        mime = mimeTypeMap.getMimeTypeFromExtension(MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(file.getTitle()));
    }
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, mime);
    try {
        SDApplication.getInstance().getCurrentActivity().startActivity(intent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Logger.logException(ERROR_TAG, "Can't find activity for mime " + mime + "\nReason:" + e.getMessage(), e);
        ToastUtils.showToast(getContext().getString(R.string.error_no_app_for_mime));
    }
}
```

But when send intent to web browser get this:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=http://some-stand.com:10012/... typ=*/* cmp=com.google.android.apps.docs/.doclist.documentopener.WebViewOpenActivity } from ProcessRecord{4138e78 8118:com.app/u0a322} (pid=8118, uid=10322) not exported from uid 10123
   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1627)
   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1579)
   at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:2671)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1509)
   at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3963)
   at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3924)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(SourceFile:820)
   at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4247)
   at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4215)
   at com.app.utils.FileUtils.startDownloadFileActivity(SourceFile:185)
   at com.app.activities.FilesActivity$1.onItemClick(SourceFile:157)
   at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:310)
   at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1145)
   at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3066)
   at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3903)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5526)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I don't understand what permission need application to open URL. And error is produced by only one device: Sony Xperia.
Application has Internet permission in AndroidManifest file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19829507/android-java-lang-securityexception-permission-denial-starting-intent)

Comment: First check Internet Permission in menifest.xml file, and then if you are using Android 6.0 (API level 23) then you need to ask run time permission for that otherwise it will not run.

Comment: Do you have an Activity in your own manifest that handles such intents ? Because other wise, it should simply open Browser.

Comment: @Alexander `android:exported="true"` does not help

Comment: @S.D. I want to open file in browser

Comment: I have similar probelm , show in xiaomi device.

Answer (score 1):

Check permission in your AndroidManifest.xml.

> android.permission.INTERNET

Comment: Application has this permission