# My app is crashing whenever I am trying to open the app info in settings tab. It also looks like referring to the old package name

Tags: android-studio

This is happening after I changed the package name. The app crashes only when I open "About"

This is the crash report

> --------- beginning of crash
>
> 07-19 18:18:21.332 2739-2739/com.wallkeeper.reader E/AndroidRuntime:
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                        Process: com.wallkeeper.reader, PID: 2739
>                                                                        java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent {
>   act=android.intent.action.VIEW
>   cmp=net.fred.feedex/.activity.AboutActivity } from
>   ProcessRecord{ca81fb2 2739:com.wallkeeper.reader/u0a64} (pid=2739,
>   uid=10064) not exported from uid 10063
>                                                                            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1599)
>                                                                            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1552)
>                                                                            at
>   android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:2658)
>                                                                            at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1507)
>                                                                            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3917)
>                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:48)
>                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:75)
>                                                                            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3877)
>                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:871)
>                                                                            at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4200)
>                                                                            at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4168)
>                                                                            at android.preference.Preference.performClick(Preference.java:1012)
>                                                                            at
>   android.preference.PreferenceScreen.onItemClick(PreferenceScreen.java:214)
>                                                                            at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:310)
>                                                                            at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1145)
>                                                                            at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3042)
>                                                                            at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3879)
>                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                            at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19829507/android-java-lang-securityexception-permission-denial-starting-intent)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `android:exported="true"` to your `AndroidManifest.xml` where your `Activity` is declared.

Also, double check that you are launching the correct configuration.

Comment: Thanks for getting back. I tried but that didn't solve the problem. There I see the old package name used starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW cmp=net.fred.feedex/.activity.AboutActivity }