# React Native Error: 'Permission Denial: starting Intent"

Tags: java, android, reactjs, native

I managed to add facebook login and google login to my application but I think I might have done something wrong. Before I started adding the logins I previously made a splash activity that user intent and since I'm a newbie I screwed up somewhere and been struggling for 2 days know. Whenever I try to do react-native run-android the project is building Successful but the simulator won't open the app automatically because I get "Starting:

```
Intent { cmp=com.happyo/.MainActivity }
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.happyo/.MainActivity } from null (pid=4430, uid=2000) not exported from uid 10085".
```

Please I am desperate I don't know how to fix it, thanks in advance!

**This is my AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.happyo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />


    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:exported="true"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="{myappkey}"/>
      <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
          android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
      <activity tools:replace="android:theme"
                android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
                android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
      <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**And these is my MainActivity**

```
package com.happyo;

import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import com.oblador.vectoricons.VectorIconsPackage;
import com.airbnb.android.react.maps.MapsPackage;
import com.BV.LinearGradient.LinearGradientPackage;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

    /**
     * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript.
     * This is used to schedule rendering of the component.
     */
    @Override
    protected String getMainComponentName() {
        return "HappyO";
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        MainApplication.getCallbackManager().onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

**My MainApplication:**

```
package com.happyo;

import android.app.Application;

import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import co.apptailor.googlesignin.RNGoogleSigninPackage;
import com.facebook.reactnative.androidsdk.FBSDKPackage;
import com.oblador.vectoricons.VectorIconsPackage;
import com.airbnb.android.react.maps.MapsPackage;
import com.BV.LinearGradient.LinearGradientPackage;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.reactnative.androidsdk.FBSDKPackage;
import com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger;
import com.magus.fblogin.FacebookLoginPackage;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import co.apptailor.googlesignin.RNGoogleSigninPackage;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private static CallbackManager mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

  protected static CallbackManager getCallbackManager() {
    return mCallbackManager;
  }

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
              new MainReactPackage(),
              new RNGoogleSigninPackage(),
              new VectorIconsPackage(),
              new MapsPackage(),
              new LinearGradientPackage(),
              new FBSDKPackage(mCallbackManager),
              new FacebookLoginPackage()
      );
    }
  };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    // If you want to use AppEventsLogger to log events.
    AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
  }
}
```

**And my SplashActivity:**

```
package com.happyo;

import android.app.Application;

import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import co.apptailor.googlesignin.RNGoogleSigninPackage;
import com.facebook.reactnative.androidsdk.FBSDKPackage;
import com.oblador.vectoricons.VectorIconsPackage;
import com.airbnb.android.react.maps.MapsPackage;
import com.BV.LinearGradient.LinearGradientPackage;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.reactnative.androidsdk.FBSDKPackage;
import com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger;
import com.magus.fblogin.FacebookLoginPackage;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import co.apptailor.googlesignin.RNGoogleSigninPackage;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private static CallbackManager mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

  protected static CallbackManager getCallbackManager() {
    return mCallbackManager;
  }

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
              new MainReactPackage(),
              new RNGoogleSigninPackage(),
              new VectorIconsPackage(),
              new MapsPackage(),
              new LinearGradientPackage(),
              new FBSDKPackage(mCallbackManager),
              new FacebookLoginPackage()
      );
    }
  };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    // If you want to use AppEventsLogger to log events.
    AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
  }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19829507/android-java-lang-securityexception-permission-denial-starting-intent

Comment: I thought I added    android:exported="true"  before but I needed to add it to AndroidManifest under MainActivity, Thank you !!

Answer (score 11):

In the manifest, Just copy `<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />` for the `<intent-filter>` in the `Splash` Activity tag:

```
<activity
  android:name=".SplashActivity"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
  android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

and paste inside of `<activity android:name=".MainActivity" />` tag like this:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
npx react-native run-android --main-activity SplashActivity
```

Comment: Can you add more details, link doc or something ?