# Android crash by java.lang.SecurityException

Tags: android, crash, android-securityexception

There are a few reports for an app of hundreds of thousands of downloads as following:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: 
  at android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:1683)
  at android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:1636)
  at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity (ActivityManagerNative.java:3159)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity (Instrumentation.java:1584)
  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult (Activity.java:4228)
  at android.support.v4.app.k.startActivityForResult (SourceFile:50)
  at android.support.v4.app.p.startActivityForResult (SourceFile:79)
  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult (Activity.java:4187)
  at android.support.v4.app.p.startActivityForResult (SourceFile:859)
  at android.app.Activity.startActivity (Activity.java:4515)
  at android.app.Activity.startActivity (Activity.java:4483)
  at android.text.style.URLSpan.onClick (URLSpan.java:75)
  at android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod.onTouchEvent (LinkMovementMethod.java:217)
  at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent (TextView.java:8524)
  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent (View.java:9942)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2672)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2358)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2672)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2358)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2672)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2358)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2672)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2358)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2672)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2358)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2672)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2358)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2672)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2358)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2672)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2358)
  at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent (DecorView.java:411)
  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent (PhoneWindow.java:1810)
  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent (Activity.java:3065)
  at android.support.v7.view.i.dispatchTouchEvent (SourceFile:71)
  at android.support.v7.view.i.dispatchTouchEvent (SourceFile:71)
  at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent (DecorView.java:373)
  at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent (View.java:10162)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent (ViewRootImpl.java:4446)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess (ViewRootImpl.java:4314)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver (ViewRootImpl.java:3861)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext (ViewRootImpl.java:3914)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward (ViewRootImpl.java:3880)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward (ViewRootImpl.java:4007)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply (ViewRootImpl.java:3888)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply (ViewRootImpl.java:4064)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver (ViewRootImpl.java:3861)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext (ViewRootImpl.java:3914)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward (ViewRootImpl.java:3880)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply (ViewRootImpl.java:3888)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver (ViewRootImpl.java:3861)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent (ViewRootImpl.java:6257)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents (ViewRootImpl.java:6196)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent (ViewRootImpl.java:6157)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent (ViewRootImpl.java:6360)
  at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent (InputEventReceiver.java:192)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce (Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next (MessageQueue.java:323)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:136)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6123)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:867)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:757)
```

I am unable to figure out a clue about the possible cause.  Could anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19829507/android-java-lang-securityexception-permission-denial-starting-intent)

Comment: Thank you for trying to help.  That mentioend thread is related to permission.  I do not see any permission involved in this crash.

Comment: Hi @Hong, Have you found any solution? I also see the same logs over the google play console.

Comment: @Harsh4789 No, unfortunately.