# Error occured while use appium connect a app on android phone

Tags: android, python, appium, appium-android

I'm recent study appium here, while I set all information needed, there has an error. This is appium logs:

```
[debug] [ADB] Running 'D:\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' with args: ["-
P",5037,"-s","ZY223MPGDF","shell","am","force-stop","io.appium.unlock"]
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Not cleaning generated files. Add `clearSystemFiles` 
capability if wanted.
[MJSONWP] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Error occured 
while starting App. Original error: Error executing adbExec. Original error: 
'Command 'D\:\\Android\\sdk\\platform-tools\\adb.exe -P 5037 -s ZY223MPGDF 
shell am start -W -n ai.zuoye.app/com.homework.app.activity.HomeActivity -S 
-a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -f 
0x10200000' exited with code 1'; Stderr: 'java.lang.SecurityException: 
Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=
[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 
cmp=ai.zuoye.app/com.homework.app.activity.HomeActivity } from null 
(pid=9092, uid=2000) not exported from uid 10213
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1684)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1637)
    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivityAndWait(ActivityManagerNative.java:3282)
    at com.android.commands.am.Am.runStart(Am.java:634)
    at com.android.commands.am.Am.onRun(Am.java:390)
    at com.android.internal.os.BaseCommand.run(BaseCommand.java:51)
    at com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:122)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:262)'; Code: '1'
at Object.wrappedLogger.errorAndThrow (../../lib/logging.js:63:13)
at ADB.callee$0$0$ (../../../lib/tools/apk-utils.js:101:9)
at tryCatch (C:\Users\Glority\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:67:40)
at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (C:\Users\Glority\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:315:22)
at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as throw] (C:\Users\Glority\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:100:21)
at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke (C:\Users\Glority\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:136:37)
at <anonymous>
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:160:7)
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 31691 ms - 1369
```

I saw it said permission deny, but I can use this to launch phones calculator, I have no idea about this.
This is my code:

```
import os
import sys
import unittest
from time import sleep
from appium import webdriver
class hh (unittest.TestCase):
    def test_addContent(self):
        desire_caps={}
        desire_caps['platformName']='Android'
        desire_caps['platformVersion']='7.1.1'
        desire_caps['appPackage']='ai.zuoye.app'
        desire_caps['appActivity']='com.homework.app.activity.HomeActivity'
        desire_caps['deviceName']='ZY223MPGDF'
        driver = webdriver.Remote("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub",desire_caps)


        sleep(10)

        driver.quit()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(hh)
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

Thanks!

Comment: You have a capability called 'platformVersioin', can you please fix this to 'platformVersion' and try again?

Comment: Still has this problem ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check few things

1) make sure your developer options is on and USB debugging option is enabled

2)check if u can open the application of phone through adb command

3)check your device is authorized by running command adb devices..if it says unauthorized make it authorized

Comment: thx！I find how to slove the problem at [Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19829507/android-java-lang-securityexception-permission-denial-starting-intent)