# Unable to launch app via ADB i get "java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent" Exception

Tags: adb, appium

While i try to launch app via adb i am getting below exception

java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent

**CMD used :** adb shell am start -n pakage/mainactivity name

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure that the activity you are launching has the right intent action and category. For example:

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
```

Check the android docs for more info:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent

There's also this very similar question with more details on android manifests:
[Android - java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19829507/android-java-lang-securityexception-permission-denial-starting-intent)

Comment: i am able to launch the same  app in an rooted device, where as  in un-rooted devices i cann't.

Comment: Just to add to the @PadmanabanGanapathy's comment - if you want this for testing purposes (i.e. don't want to add `android:exported="true"` to you `AndroidManifest.xml`, you need to run `adb root` and then `adb shell am start -n pakage/mainactivity name`