# Build successful, but "Failed to start the app"

Tags: react-native, crash

Hay dear people!

i'm struggeling to make my App running on the emulator. With the command "react-native run-android" it's builded successfully, but then it's says that it's failed to start the app. Also when the app is running and i want to start it it closes instantly.
I get the following error message:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 17s
388 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 386 up-to-date
info Connecting to the development server...                                                                                                                              
info Starting the app on "emulator-5554"...                                                                                                                               
Starting: Intent { cmp=de.orgasoft.crmvertriebsvorgaenge/.MainActivity }                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                                                          
Exception occurred while executing 'start':                                                                                                                               
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { flg=0x10000000 cmp=de.orgasoft.crmvertriebsvorgaenge/.MainActivity } from null (pid=14085, uid=2000) not exported from uid 10121                                                                                                                                                  
        at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStackSupervisor.checkStartAnyActivityPermission(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1032)                                               
        at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter.executeRequest(ActivityStarter.java:999)                                                                                 
        at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter.execute(ActivityStarter.java:669)
        at com.android.server.wm.ActivityTaskManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityTaskManagerService.java:1100)
        at com.android.server.wm.ActivityTaskManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityTaskManagerService.java:1072)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityAsUserWithFeature(ActivityManagerService.java:3678)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerShellCommand.runStartActivity(ActivityManagerShellCommand.java:544)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerShellCommand.onCommand(ActivityManagerShellCommand.java:186)
        at android.os.BasicShellCommandHandler.exec(BasicShellCommandHandler.java:98)
        at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:44)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onShellCommand(ActivityManagerService.java:10521)
        at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:929)
        at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:813)
        at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityManager.java:5027)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2883)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1159)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1123)
error Failed to start the app.
Error: Command failed: C:\Users\ako\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 shell am start -n de.orgasoft.crmvertriebsvorgaenge/de.orgasoft.crmvertriebsvorgaenge.MainActivity
    at makeError (C:\Entwicklung\_Work_Projects\CRM\mobile-crm-internal\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)      
    at Function.module.exports.sync (C:\Entwicklung\_Work_Projects\CRM\mobile-crm-internal\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\node_modules\execa\index.js:338:15)
    at tryLaunchAppOnDevice (C:\Entwicklung\_Work_Projects\CRM\mobile-crm-internal\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\tryLaunchAppOnDevice.js:58:22)
    at C:\Entwicklung\_Work_Projects\CRM\mobile-crm-internal\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:104:39
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at runOnAllDevices (C:\Entwicklung\_Work_Projects\CRM\mobile-crm-internal\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:102:48)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (C:\Entwicklung\_Work_Projects\CRM\mobile-crm-internal\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:186:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

Hope someone have some hints to solve that!

Comment: This should fix your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19829507/android-java-lang-securityexception-permission-denial-starting-intent

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I got it.

The error message disappeared after i changed

```
 <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">

      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.zoontek.rnbootsplash.RNBootSplashActivity"
            android:theme="@style/BootTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

to

```
   <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
    </application>
```

And the crashing disappeared after i deleted the following line:

```
import com.facebook.react.BuildConfig;
```

in \android\app\src\main\java\de\orgasoft\crmvertriebsvorgaenge\MainApplication.java